# Recover VBA Code from Access DB File

Tags: ms-access, vba

all of a sudden my ACCESS 2010 VBA Code cannot be opened any longer.
I receive the error, that ID is no longe an Index of the table.

Pressing ALT - F11 does not open VB any longer.

Any ideas how I can recover my VBA Code?

Comment: When do you receive the error?  When the db is first opened?  If so, you could try opening the file while holding down the [Shift] key.  This will prevent any startup forms or Autoexec macros from running, which may allow you to get at your code before getting the error message.

Comment: I can open the DB (an error poping up, but I can open it)
Then, when I douple click on a module, the error I described pops up and finally nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Please try some of the ideas here (although it depends on the database format, AC97/2000 etc.): http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html. Perhaps if you can repair the database enough so that whilst the structure may be truncated you could perhaps still get at your VBA code.

Comment: @Proto Bassi: Which of the methods listed on that website did you actually try?  It is a pretty exhaustive list (re-import objects into new db, decompile, SaveAsText/LoadFromText, etc.).

Comment: I tried:
<br>Build in repair
<br>Import
<br>Delete References
<br>Deleted all Indexes in the tables
<br>Save as Text

Comment: How did you delete the references if you cannot open the VBA IDE?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can open the DatabaseTools. From there I can delete the references between the tables and get rid of any Primary keys

Answer (score 1):

I have found that [Decompile](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm) followed by compact and repair will often fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Developer Tab per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx  and click the Visual Basic button.

Comment: Developer Tab is enabled and the VB Button does the samme as described above.

Comment: In ACCESS there is nothing like a developer tab. But I know where to press to get to VB.

Comment: So you clicked the VB button under Database Tools and nothing happens?  Can you test the DB on another machine to determine if it's a problem with your OS?

Comment: I made a backup two days ago and that one works without a problem. But I would loose two days.